# Pyspark toPandas ValueError: Found non-unique column index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I get the following error when I try to convert pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe with the method `toPandas`. I don't understand the reason for the error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_64705/3870041712.py in <module>
----> 1 df_who.limit(10).toPandas()

/opt/miniforge/miniforge/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2130                     if len(batches) > 0:
   2131                         table = pyarrow.Table.from_batches(batches)
-> 2132                         pdf = table.to_pandas()
   2133                         pdf = _check_dataframe_convert_date(pdf, self.schema)
   2134                         return _check_dataframe_localize_timestamps(pdf, timezone)

/opt/miniforge/miniforge/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas()

/opt/miniforge/miniforge/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table._to_pandas()

/opt/miniforge/miniforge/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in table_to_blockmanager(options, table, categories, ignore_metadata, types_mapper)
    786 
    787     _check_data_column_metadata_consistency(all_columns)
--> 788     columns = _deserialize_column_index(table, all_columns, column_indexes)
    789     blocks = _table_to_blocks(options, table, categories, ext_columns_dtypes)
    790 

/opt/miniforge/miniforge/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in _deserialize_column_index(block_table, all_columns, column_indexes)
    901 
    902     # ARROW-1751: flatten a single level column MultiIndex for pandas 0.21.0
--> 903     columns = _flatten_single_level_multiindex(columns)
    904 
    905     return columns

/opt/miniforge/miniforge/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in _flatten_single_level_multiindex(index)
   1142         # Cheaply check that we do not somehow have duplicate column names
   1143         if not index.is_unique:
-> 1144             raise ValueError('Found non-unique column index')
   1145 
   1146         return pd.Index(

ValueError: Found non-unique column index
```

Comment: It seems that the answer is in your error message. `ValueError: Found non-unique column index`. A few lines up, you see a comment before the block which caused this error: `# Cheaply check that we do not somehow have duplicate column names`. In other words, in your Spark df, you must have columns which have identic titles. So it does not let you do the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check columns of pyspark dataframe, There is repeat column name in your dataframe according to your error.